# SQL Server 2008 - Best Backup solution

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

I'm setting up a SQL Server 2008 server on a production server, which way is the best to backup this data? Should I use replication and then backup that server? Should I just use a simple command-line script and export the data? Which replication method should i use?

The server is going to be pretty loaded so I need an efficent method.

I have access to multiple computers that I can use.

Comment: Please clarify - are you aware that SQL Server has a BACKUP DATABASE command?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm wondering what would be the best and most efficent solution on a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple yet good solution is to run a full backup using *sqlcmd* (formerly *osql*) locally, then copy the BAK file over the network to a NAS or other store. It's sub-optimal in terms of network/disk usage, but it's very safe because every backup is independent and given that the process is very simple it is also very robust.

Moreover, this even works in Express editions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm going to test this solution on our development server.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" backup solutions depends upon your recovery criteria.

If you need immediate access to the data in the event of a failure, a three server database mirroring scenario (live, mirror and witness) would seem to fit - although your application may need to be adapted to make use of automatic failover. "Log shipping" may produce similar results (although without automatic failover, or need for a witness).

If, however, there's some wiggle room in the recovery time, regular scheduled backups of the database (e.g., via SQL Agent) and it's transaction logs will allow you to do point-in-time restores. The frequency of backups would be determined by database size, how frequently the data is updated, and how far you are willing to rollback the database in the event of complete failure (unless you can extract a transaction log backup out of a failed server, you can only recover to the latest backup)

If you're looking to simply rollback to known-good states after, say, user error, you can make use of database snapshots as a lightweight "backup" scenario - but these are useless in the event of server failure. They're near instantaneous to create, and only take up room when the data changed - but incur a slight performance overhead.

Of course, these aren't the only backup solutions, nor are they mutually exclusive - just the ones that came to mind.